# Remote debug manage application (c#)

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Is it possible to remote debug a C# application? Which VS versions allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I have done this with VS 2003, 2005, 2008 and am certain 2010 also has this feature.

Attaching to a remote process is only available to the Pro editions and above.

See the [product comparison sheet](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=727bcfb0-b575-47ab-9fd8-4ee067bb3a37&displaylang=en) for VS 2008, from MS.